# How to call asp.net webservice using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-webservice

I have asp.net webservice call in android but it gives error `baseUrl must end in /`.

This is my url

```
 private static String url = "http://192.138.0.100/Client.asmx?op=Client_Login";
  //create Interface
    public interface ApiInterface {
        @GET("api/{MobileNo}/{Pass}/{AppVer}")
        Call<Login> authenticate(@Path("MobileNo") String MobileNo, @Path("Pass") String password, @Path("AppVer") String AppVer);
        @POST("api/{MobileNo}/{Pass}/{AppVer}")
        Call<Login> registration(@Path("MobileNo") String email, @Path("Pass") String password, @Path("AppVer") String AppVer);
    }
```

This method use to call webservice but it gives error

```
 private void loginProcessWithRetrofit(final String mobilno, String pwd,String Appver){
    ApiInterface mApiService = this.getInterfaceService();
    Call<Login> mService = mApiService.authenticate(mobilno, pwd,Appver);
    mService.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
            Login mLoginObject = response.body();
            String returnedResponse = mLoginObject.isLogin;
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Returned " + returnedResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //showProgress(false);
            if(returnedResponse.trim().equals("1")){
                // redirect to Main Activity page

            }
            if(returnedResponse.trim().equals("0")){
                // use the registration button to register
               // failedLoginMessage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.registration_message));
               // mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your network connection and internet permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
private ApiInterface getInterfaceService() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    final ApiInterface mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    return mInterfaceService;
}
```

Comment: what error it gives ????/

Comment: baseUrl must end in /

Comment: just add an "/" to `http://192.138.0.100/Client.asmx?op=Client_Login/` like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error because you add your query parameter in `baseurl` first.

your url : `http://192.138.0.100/Client.asmx?op=Client_Login/api/{MobileNo}/{Pass}/{AppVer}`

it should be like this: `http://192.138.0.100/Client_Login/api/{MobileNo}/{Pass}/{AppVer}`

Query parameter always comes in end of the URL

Please check your Url once.

as you mention in comment you can do this by following:

```
 public interface ApiInterface {
        @GET("api/")
        Call<Login> authenticate(@Query("MobileNo") String MobileNo, @Query("Pass") String password, @Query("AppVer") String AppVer);
        @POST("api/")
        Call<Login> registration(@Query("MobileNo") String MobileNo, @Query("Pass") String password, @Query("AppVer") String AppVer);
    }
```

Comment: GET /Client.asmx/Client_Login?MobileNo=string&Pass=string&AppVer=string   I want pass like that how

Comment: POST /Client.asmx/Client_Login

Comment: Try `@UrlEncode` if it is not json request to the server. By default retrofit allow json request.